# UWP app is not scaling

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to make text editor for Windows (PC) in UWP but the scaling is not working, I've done the same in WPF and it worked.

The page size is set to 800x600, these are columns:

```
 <Grid Background="White" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="filename" Margin="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Untitled</TextBlock>
        <Border Margin="5" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBox x:Name="text" AcceptsReturn="True"
                     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" TextChanged="text_TextChanged"/>
        </Border>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2"  Margin="3,3" Orientation="Horizontal" MinHeight="31" >
            <Button x:Name="saveButton" FontSize="15" Content="Save" Margin="0,0,0,-0.125" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="saveButton_Click"  />
            <Button x:Name="button" Content="Save as..."  Margin="5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Click="button_Click" />
            <Button x:Name="loadButton" FontSize="15" Content="Read" Margin="5,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="loadButton_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Title is in 1st row, content is in 2nd, buttons (save, load) are in 3rd, it looks like grid it wouldn't exist:

[That's with normal size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBDrC.png)

[After size change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bgHW.png)

How do I fix it?

Comment: Is the grid inside some another item?

Comment: Only in page, I will edit and put entire code.

Answer (score 1):

> The page size is set to 800x600

If you've set the page size to 800x600 like this: `<Page Width="800" Height="600"...` it will always be 800x600 and it will not scale. If you want it to scale properly, just don't set these properties.

I assume you wanted to set the size of the app when it starts for the first time. You can approach it by setting the [`ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.preferredlaunchviewsize.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).

Also I recommend to use the [`RichEditBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/rich-edit-box) to display and edit text files.

Comment: Thank you, I've changed page size to auto and now it works.